# log4j2 what happens when disk space is full

Tags: java, logging, out-of-memory, log4j2

I am using log4j2 for logging in my java application which is configured to write logs to a file. What happens when the disk space goes full? Does log4j2 buffer the logs until it gets the disk to flush? If yes, could it cause OOM error?

Comment: personnal experience: log4j crash but app keep running. But it may depend on the condifuration. You can try it by writing a small app that write logs to an usb flash drive.

Comment: @jhamon "condifuration"? Funny typo ;-)

Comment: @Andreas I left shifted my keyboard middle row... I type fast! Next step is to type correctly :)

Answer (score 2):

Log4j2 is designed as an audit logging framework. This means that if logging is critical to your application, such that the application should fail if logging failed, Log4j2 can accomplish this.

All built-in appenders have a configuration attribute `ignoreExceptions` for this purpose. From the [manual](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html):

> The default is true, causing exceptions encountered while appending events to be internally logged and then ignored. When set to false exceptions will be propagated to the caller, instead.

Then consider writing a new Appender that wraps whichever appender is accessing the disk, and tries to do something sensible when it detects IOExceptions. Maybe get it to wrap the underlying Appenders write methods in a try-catch block, and send you or a sysadmin an email.

---

The idea is to contain the total possible disk space used by log4j2 just like max heap for JVM. So you have to use a size based policy along with a max rollover for all the appenders.

If it works as expected then you shouldn't be using more than 10GB per appender at anytime since the log4j2 also uses some compression on rolled over files.

eg.

```xml
<Policies>
   <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="1 GB" /> 
...
<Policies>
...
<DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10"/>
```

If you have java application server running with several apps. They all log with Log4J into the same file system, which got created only for that reason. From time to time it happens that the file system runs out of space and the app gets

```
log4j:ERROR Failed to flush writer,                                             
java.io.IOException
```

and whether you get OOM error(out-of-memory)depends upon the java heap size and the amount of log you expect for the application for single transaction and how many blocks of data it is supposed to write.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Does it mean that not writing a log (due to any error/exception/disk full issue) does not have any impact on Java application?